# AsyncThunkAction does not fit to AnyAction?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

codesandbox is here https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-github-issues-example-03-final-async-su4hz?file=/src/features/issuesList/IssuesListPage.tsx

I've used AppDispatch which suggested https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-usedispatch-hook  and this question [How do I resolve 'Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction' using Redux Toolkit (with TypeScript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238338/how-do-i-resolve-property-type-is-missing-in-type-asyncthunkaction-using-re)
but transpile is faield.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(action: AnyAction): AnyAction', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<RepoDetails, { org: string; repo: string; }, { dispatch: ThunkDispatch<CombinedState<{ issuesDisplay: CurrentDisplayState; repoDetails: RepoDetailsState; issues: IssuesState; comments: CommentsState; }>, null, AnyAction> & ThunkDispatch<...> & Dispatch<...>; state: RepoDetailsState; rejectValue: MyK...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
      Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<RepoDetails, { org: string; repo: string; }, { dispatch: ThunkDispatch<CombinedState<{ issuesDisplay: CurrentDisplayState; repoDetails: RepoDetailsState; issues: IssuesState; comments: CommentsState; }>, null, AnyAction> & ThunkDispatch<...> & Dispatch<...>; state: RepoDetailsState; rejectValue: MyK...' but required in type 'AnyAction'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(asyncAction: ThunkAction<Promise<PayloadAction<RepoDetails, string, { arg: { org: string; repo: string; }; requestId: string; }, never> | PayloadAction<MyKnownError | undefined, string, { ...; }, SerializedError>> & { ...; }, CombinedState<...>, null, AnyAction>): Promise<...> & { ...; }', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<RepoDetails, { org: string; repo: string; }, { dispatch: ThunkDispatch<CombinedState<{ issuesDisplay: CurrentDisplayState; repoDetails: RepoDetailsState; issues: IssuesState; comments: CommentsState; }>, null, AnyAction> & ThunkDispatch<...> & Dispatch<...>; state: RepoDetailsState; rejectValue: MyK...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThunkAction<Promise<PayloadAction<RepoDetails, string, { arg: { org: string; repo: string; }; requestId: string; }, never> | PayloadAction<MyKnownError | undefined, string, { ...; }, SerializedError>> & { ...; }, CombinedState<...>, null, AnyAction>'.
      Types of parameters 'getState' and 'getState' are incompatible.
        Type 'CombinedState<{ issuesDisplay: CurrentDisplayState; repoDetails: RepoDetailsState; issues: IssuesState; comments: CommentsState; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'RepoDetailsState': openIssuesCount, error
  Overload 3 of 3, '(asyncAction: ThunkAction<Promise<PayloadAction<RepoDetails, string, { arg: { org: string; repo: string; }; requestId: string; }, never> | PayloadAction<MyKnownError | undefined, string, { ...; }, SerializedError>> & { ...; }, CombinedState<...>, undefined, AnyAction>): Promise<...> & { ...; }', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<RepoDetails, { org: string; repo: string; }, { dispatch: ThunkDispatch<CombinedState<{ issuesDisplay: CurrentDisplayState; repoDetails: RepoDetailsState; issues: IssuesState; comments: CommentsState; }>, null, AnyAction> & ThunkDispatch<...> & Dispatch<...>; state: RepoDetailsState; rejectValue: MyK...' is not assignable to parameter of type 
ThunkAction<Promise<PayloadAction<RepoDetails, string, { arg: { org: string; repo: string; }; requestId: string; }, never> | PayloadAction<MyKnownError | undefined, string, { ...; }, SerializedError>> & { ...; }, CombinedState<...>, undefined, AnyAction>'.
      Types of parameters 'getState' and 'getState' are incompatible.
        Type 'CombinedState<{ issuesDisplay: CurrentDisplayState; repoDetails: RepoDetailsState; issues: IssuesState; comments: CommentsState; }>' is not assignable to type 'RepoDetailsState'.ts(2769)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use **RootState** for thunkAPI parameter types in createAsyncThunk function.

```
  {
    dispatch: AppDispatch
    state: RootState
    rejectValue: MyKnownError
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this error because I used the wrong type for dispatch. I used AppDispatch for the thunkAPI param types, but where I tried to use the thunk I explicitly declared the wrong dispatch type. The reverse is surely also possible. Read here about AppDispatch: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type

Using the right type for RootState like Hiroyuki Shirakawa said is a good thing to look for too.

Read here about createAsyncThunk in TypeScript: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk